# how to work with loops to control a movieClip ???!!! 

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

i was working with AS2.0 and was trying to make an .swf movie that stops the movieClip in a limit of time and plays it in another limit. and this is what i've got so far, it works without the loop and with if condition but i need to have a loop so it would work as i want it to. please help me, thanks.

```
myDate = new Date();
hrs = myDate.getHours();

while ( hrs >6 && hrs <21)  // time range i want the movieclip to stop
{
stop();     // to stop the timeline
Night.stop();   // " Night " is the instance name of the movieclip
hrs = myDate.getHours();    // to update the time 
}

stop();     // to stop the timeline
Night.play();   // it's out of the time limit so the movieclip should play
```

Comment: I think you may need to rethink your use of the infamous triple-interrobang in the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In flash + actionscript you would want to utilize the timeline to your advantage, an interval, or an enter frame handler rather than a loop. The loop is designed to execute repetitive (or similar) code until a condition is true.

When using a loop within a frame on the timeline or a symbol, it will not allow the next frame to draw and refresh - this essentially times out the player (do you get a 15-second timeout error in Flash?) and everything "freezes."

The "enter frame" way would be (this is off the top of my head):

```
onEnterFrame = function(){ // execute the following on every frame
    hrs = (new Date()).getHours(); // get the current hour 
    if ( hrs >6 && hrs <21) { // time range i want the movieclip to stop
        Night.gotoAndStop(1); // stop and reset Night
        Night.alpha = 0; // hide Night
    } else {
        /*
            if Night's frame is "1" then we can assume that Night is not playing,
            however, in the event it is playing already, it will just keep playing
            without missing a beat
        */
        if ( Night.currentFrame == 1 ) {
            Night.alpha = 1; // show Night
            Night.gotoAndPlay(2); // advance to the next frame
        }
    }
}

stop(); // stop the main timeline
Night.play(); // play Night by default
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but it still doesn't work like i want it to , it does stop when i play in the time range and to see it plays out of the time range i have to restart the flash player , you see this is a logo i want to put it on a website , and i can't change it or restart it manually, i want it to play  when its out of the time range and stops in the time range automatically , that was the reason i used a loop in my scripts, i would be glad if u could help me with this, i have just stated scripting and there are many thing i need to learn. thanks again

Comment: @naskaz, sorry I had an error in the logic, I have updated the answer. I was originally only getting the date once - it never updated. Now the date is refreshed on every enter frame. please try again.

Comment: thanks for the time you've put into this script to help me, i'm really sorry but since you are a professional i was wondering if u could answer another question, can i do the same thing with days ? like the movie blink on Sat & Sun and stop blinking the rest of the weak ? am i suppose to use this : myDate= newDate () ; dys = myDate.getDays(); ? and what should i put in the if condition the date of the day or the name of them like " Sat" & " Sun" .

Comment: @naskaz see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#getDay()
day = (new Day()).getDay();
if ( day === 0 || day === 6 ) { it is sat or sun }

Answer (score 0):

i'm not an AS2.0 programmer, but maybe adding a delay inside the while loop could help, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help you out, it gives a great breakdown of how it works as well http://www.quip.net/blog/2006/flash/how-to-loop-three-times

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of onEnterFrame event which would not hang the movie

```
this.onEnterFrame = function() {
    var myDate = new Date();
    var hrs = myDate.getHours();

    while ( hrs >6 && hrs <21)  // time range i want the movieclip to stop
    {
    stop();     // to stop the timeline
    Night.stop();   // " Night " is the instance name of the movieclip
    hrs = myDate.getHours();    // to update the time 
    }

    stop();     // to stop the timeline
    Night.play();
}
```